# How to connect localhost database with firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, localhost

I am creating an android app which stores data in the firebase database and I have made an Admin Panel which stores data in the localhost database. So I want to retrieve data of firebase and show in the localhost database. What should I do?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to store? Just partial data, a specific selection? The entire database? What database are you using locally? In general, you should be able to connect to the firestore database just fine and use your local database to enhance the data you retrieve from there, or you could use rules to secure data you only want visible on an administrative dashboard.

Comment: I am trying to access the data of Realtime data base. just like an e-commerce app,  if the order is successfully placed then the order details are saved in the realtime database of firebase, but I through an admin panel which is completely based on php want to show the order details on the web.

Comment: You should have a look at the firebase admin sdk for php. You can use it to query data directly from the realtime db. The admin sdk as opposed to the client sdk is designed to run in a privileged environment (a server, for example) and bypasses any rules that you have set for regular users by use of a server account key. https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/realtime-database.html#retrieving-data

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. I am gonna look at it.